# How To Compile QFtp Example in Qt 5?

Tags: qt

I have application which uses QFtp class.I have made in Qt 4 version.
But now i want to complie QFtp classe in Qt5 but it's showing some error like:
'QFtp' doesn't name and type.

how to resolve this issue. I don't want to use QNetworkAccessManager. is there any way to this?
Thank you

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://forum.qt.io/topic/23904/qtftp-and-qthttp-compatibility-add-ons-for-qhttp-and-qftp-classes-in-qt-5/15 ?

Comment: Yes! this link is helpful but the website which provides source code for QFtp adds-on is not working?

Answer (score 7):

For the sake of completeness, the steps to use the add-ons are:

- Download the sources for the add-on from https://github.com/qt/qtftp
- Extract the sources somewhere (e.g. Qt5.x.y/Src/qtmyaddon)
- Open a console in that folder
- Read readme.txt and run the appropriate commands with the latest QT version
- Run qmake
- Run make (or nmake or mingw32-make or whatever)
- Run sudo make install (nmake install, mingw32-make install, ...)
- In the .pro file of your project, add "QT += myaddon" (e.g. "QT += ftp")
- Run qmake on your project
- Compile your project